# Spree 1.3.2 not showing My Account and Login/Logout links, and Spree::User object in console

Tags: ruby-on-rails, spree

I have installed spree 1.3.2 in a new rails project. After bundle install, I ran the spree install cmd, and it ran perfectly fine.

After starting the app on my local server, I got the sample data and products. But I am not getting any links related to accounts. e.g. /account, or /login

In the console, I get an error when I look for Spree::User Object. I am not able to figure out why is the Object not coming up and why some urls are missing.

Can anyone please provide some pointers ?

Thanks,
Gaurav

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you forgot to install the [spree_auth_devise](https://github.com/spree/spree_auth_devise) extension. Please consult that project's README for instructions on how to install it.