# Requested URL /login was not found on this server after deploying Rails Spree application through Capistrano

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql, capistrano, spree

Today I deployed a Spree Commerce application on a commercial server. The problem I am having is that the login page is not working and I hope someone here can give me advice.

I am quite new with Ruby on Rails and just tweaked the standard Spree Commerce application a little bit. On my local machine everything is working fine (possible to add products, login, et cetera). The server and me are running Ruby 1.9.3 and Rails 3.2.14.

After putting everything in a git repository, configuring the deploy.rb file according to the website of the hosting company, and running "bundle install", "exec rake assets:precompile", "cap:deploy:setup" and "cap:deploy" the whole thing was successfully deployed to the server.

When you visited the website you at first got an elegant error message from Phusion Passenger that said that database.yml was missing. This was resolved after I a database.yml file to rails/shared/config on the server (I had to make the config folder too) with the following contents (username and password same as locally):

```
production:
  adapter: postgresql
  encoding: utf8
  database: [name]
  pool: 5
  timeout: 5000
  username: [username]
  password: [password]
  host: localhost
```

Now, when I surf to the website the index page is showing, I can view the shopping card and it is possible to search for products. Unfortunately, when I try to login I get the following message:

[image: The requested URL /login was not found on this server.]

Someone else on SO had a similar issue [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14893821/spree-1-3-2-not-showing-my-account-and-login-logout-links-and-spreeuser-objec) with a non-working admin/login page, only then on the local machine. This individual got the advice to install the spree_auth_devise extension. I did include this in my Gemfile and locally the login functionality is working fine so that is not the issue in my case.

/edit Furthermore, this might be relevant, when I run rake db:bootstrap I get the following message:

```
-bash-4.1$ rake db:bootstrap
This task will destroy any data in the database. Are you sure you want to 
continue? [y/n] y
rake aborted!
database configuration does not specify adapter
```

I hope someone can enlighten me!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well the problem was solved by asking the nice folks at #spree on freenode IRC. By adding

```
Spree::Config.set(:allow_ssl_in_production => false)
```

to config/initializers/spree.rb, committing and pushing to the git repository and running cap:deploy again the login page is working!

I had the standard setup of the database which used SSL in production mode and my website was not setup to use SSL. The simple fix was to disable SSL in production mode.

Since I have no SSL certificate or support (in the end I do want this of course because it is more safe) this gave a 301 error in the production log on the server at rails/config/production.log.